# Unity：Use Different Compilers For Different File Types

Tags: unity-game-engine, ide, editor

Can the unity External script editor be extended to open up different extensions with different editors？

I want to use vscode to open `.shader` files, while I want CSharp scripts to use Visual Studio. With the External script editor I can only set one editor for all extensions.

Comment: As far as I know, you can change the External Tools to ONE IDE. So if for some reason you want to use different IDE for scripts and different for shaders, you’ll have a hard time switching all the time. I recommend you to get used to one of them. What is the reason for using different IDEs for these tasks anyway?

Comment: Sorry i don't know how to reply。My partner likes to use vscode to edit the shader，But vscode is not very convenient for C# script support, although it can be solved by installing plugins.So he asked me to find a solution.I am trying to find a solution.Hope to make a configuration file to modify in unity@B3NII

Comment: It's a good question, and I also would like to make it so VSCode opens when I edit Shaders and Visual Studio when I edit C# files. Anyone knows if it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

I had this question myself, and I found a workaround. Not the solution I was hoping for, but still good enough for me.

You can set Visual Studio as the main editor for all extension in Unity. Then, from Visual Studio, you can set the `.shader` extension to be edited by default using Visual Studio code.

To do this:

1. Go in Unity -> Edit -> Preferences -> External Tools and set `External Script Editor` to Visual Studio. I also ticked all the tickboxes to make sure all files were generated; this is useful because when opening an asset file it will appear with its contextual files in VS Solution Explorer, which makes the next step easier.
2. Create a Shader and double click it to open it up in Visual Studio.
3. In Visual Studio, go to the Solution Explorer and right click the `.shader` file, then select `Open With...`. Scroll to find Visual Studio Code, and click `Set as Default`.

From now on, every time you edit a Shader file, Visual Studio will fire up, then Visual Studio code will open up immediately thereafter, with the shader file in it.

This will reuse an open instance of Visual Studio if it is already open, which is what I have most of the time, so the overhead of opening up Visual Studio to open Visual Studio code is nullified most of the time for me.